# The rounded corners Ajax effect is useful for?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-plugins, rounded-corners

I still don't get the point of investing some coding time to add this effect even knowing that it will (probably) not be compatible with all the web browsers available out there. I want to hear your opinions.

Comment: What do rounded corners have to do with Ajax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same reason your toilet seat isn't square.  Round just *feels* better.

Comment: That's 'cause the toilet really feels better XD

Answer (score 3):

So you don't hurt yourself trying to create your own.

You see, awhile back as rounded corners grew in popularity, a series of unfortunate accidents occurred.  As newer, less experienced designers and developers were seeing the rise in popularity of rounded corners, they saw it as being time to upgrade their square corners.

Sadly in their excitement, they took for granted the safety needed in working with sharp square corners. At this time a single monitor setup was more the norm.  So as they flipped back and forth between their design tool and the tutorial, tragedy struck.

The community took notice, and knew something had to be done. "This must be automated! And to make sure people find it quicker, tell them its AJAX that's preforming the magic."

And the rest is history my friend.

Answer (score 2):

Graphic design?..

Answer (score 0):

just to give a good graphical look to your web.

Answer (score 0):

Presentation? corporate ID? Layout? Nice to have?

Answer (score 0):

To engage your users... Or you could save some real coding time and just go with plain old text.